# Why don't other sites recognize like Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, consecutive-days

I have 14 accounts overall. I visit every site daily through my [SE link](https://stackexchange.com/users/1719640/crazy-buddy?tab=accounts). Once we open a site through that link, it arrives at our profile page. When I visit area51, it shows **0 secs ago** every time in the "seen" option. It is very fast and recognizes our entry. It also updates the consecutive.

But, other sites (like Physics, MSO, SU), we'll have to refresh the page again. At our first entry, it says `seen: 6 hours ago` (or any last update from the previous visit). After a refresh (based on how many seconds we take), it says `4 secs ago` - something like that.

I tried for Graphics.SE. I opened my profile, it said `seen: 22 hours ago`. I didn't visit it after that. The same thing I done for area51. The next day, I clicked on the consecutive and it told that I haven't logged yesterday. But, area51 said that I have logged in. So, the method is this. Area 51 recognizes *immediately* while other sites take a second refresh. Why is that so?

Why can't we have other sites with the same method (no refresh)..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other sites don't take a second to refresh, in fact it's instantaneous, it just happens in the background *while you're seeing the page*, so **only** you seeing the page *that* time shows the previous data.

Why does it behave unlike Area 51?  Because Area 51 is *very* different and a totally different project and code.  Re-tagging this as a feature-request, as it's not a bug.

Comment: @CrazyBuddy - I don't see an account of yours on Graphics.SE, do you mean Graphic Design?  Consecutive logins are only updated if you visit on *another day* (UTC midnight reset, been this way from the beginning), and the home page does not count as being active, *anything* else does.